# Where should the code reside to update Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a Firestore database that I want to constantly be updating (and listeners in my code to constantly be responding to backend updates), should the code that's responsible for updating the database belong in the android app that will be available for download to other people? Or is it supposed to be somewhere else?

For example, the code for creating a document with user info within the collection "Users" belongs in every instance of the app that I publish, because I want every user using my app to be able to write their login info to the Firestore database after they register through Firebase Auth.

But if I have a different collection of data that I want to be available to all users using my app, and I want to be updating that data constantly, should I be updating it with code that goes in with my production level app, or should that be happening somewhere else? And if it should be happening somewhere else, where should that be/how should that be done?

I'd appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer to my own question. Firebase provides users with Cloud Functions, which can run on the server-side to respond to new data events.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in Realtime Database, it will mean you don't have to write any of these listeners to the data and it does it all automatically. Check it out here;
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore